# App_GlobalResources broken in ASP.NET MVC 2 and VS 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2

Good day!

I have installed VS 2010 Express and resource files in `App_GlobalResources` are not compiled into strongly typed `Resources` class. More specifically no more code generation take place.

I have tested with my MVC project (updated from MVC 1.0 and VS2008) and with blank ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project generated by VS and got error (even when trying to run code generation by hand in right click menu):

```
Cannot find custom tool ‘GlobalResourceProxyGenerator’ on this system.
```

When I change custom tool to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` like suggested here:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/15/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

the classes are generated.

The `App_GlobalResources` works for Web Forms projects on the same machine\VS.

Should I don't use `App_GlobalResources` for MVC at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick solution is just to create `Resources` folder, move all resx files there and change properties of resx like desribed here:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/15/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

The Resource strings will be accessible via `Resources..